# How do I shutdown a remote server via ssh without getting a 'broken pipe' error?

Tags: bash, ssh, shutdown

I need to reboot a remote server via ssh in a script and receive a 0 exit code.

I have everything set up to use keys instead of a password; so I'm able to login remotely. The problem is that when I send the `shutdown -r` command, ssh will report a broken pipe.

I've tried using `-oConnectTimeout=1` and `-oTCPKeepAlive=no`. I've also tried delaying the shutdown with `shutdown -r -t 30` but it doesn't appear to work.

```
ssh thor@$hammer_time -oBatchMode=yes "sync; sync; shutdown -r"
```

Right now the script will hang for a minute, and report a non-zero exit status: `broken pipe` which I would expect since the server just rebooted. How do I get ssh to login, and exit with the reboot's exit code after sending the reboot command without getting a broken pipe error?

Comment: For me all of the following `ssh` commands exit normally with status `0` on Ubuntu 18.04. `ssh sever 'sudo shutdown -r'`, `ssh sever 'sudo shutdown -r 0'`, `ssh sever -oBatchMode=yes 'sudo shutdown -r 0'`. I could not reproduce the broken pipe error.

Comment: I didn't even think about that! They are using a different OS on the server and are using a custom shutdown script. Thanks! Should I delete this question then? @Socowi?

Comment: You *could* delete this answer, but it would be even better if you could answer your own question so that others with the same problem can benefit from your findings.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way is, this way you are restarting the machine ... a "-h" flag will just shut it down.

```
sudo shutnow -r now
```

If the hang up is problematic, the following might work,

```
nohup sudo shutdown -r now
```

You are commanding the job to run in the background after you are disconnected

```
gnome-session-quit --power-off
gnome-session-quit --reboot --force
```

Is for Linux users